# Hibernate self reference table not saving parent id

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, self-reference, self-referencing-table

I try to save both childs and their parent at one shot in self-referencing table. But child rows at db have null parent ids after saving. Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = "id")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Generator.UUID2_GENERATOR_NAME)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "main_category_id")
    private UUID mainCategoryId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Category mainCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainCategory", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Category> subCategories;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

I'm setting childs and parent at both directions, but main_category_id saving as null at database.
Code for saving look like this:

```
    @Transactional
    public List<CategoryDto> get(UUID userId) {
        List<Category> categoriesToSave = new ArrayList<>();
            for (YoungWithPetCategories cat : YoungWithPetCategories.values()) {
                Category category = new Category();
                category.setName(cat.name());
                category.setUserId(userId);
                List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String subCat : cat.getSubCategories()) {
                    Category subCategory = new Category();
                    subCategory.setName(subCat);
                    subCategory.setMainCategory(category);
                    subCategory.setUserId(userId);
                    subCategories.add(subCategory);
                }
                transactionCategory.setSubCategories(subCategories);
                categoriesToSave.add(transactionCategory);
            }
            categoryRepository.saveAll(categoriesToSave);
    }
```

I tried to save childs, not parrent, and to save all of them at once.
Is it even possible to save such self-reference entities at one shot or should i save them apart?

Comment: Solved be removing "insertable = false, updatable = false" and "private UUID mainCategoryId;"